# r read NetCDF and export as shapefile

Tags: r, raster, shapefile, netcdf, rgdal

I need to read a NetCDF file with R and export each time step as a smoothed polygon shapefile.
I have two problems: smoothing the raster and exporting to shapefile with proper projection from the NC file.
The output is a regular grid and is not projected.

Here is a sample code:

```
>NCFileName = MyncFile.nc
NCFile = open.ncdf(NCFileName) 
NCFile 
[1] "file CF_OUTPUT.nc has 6 dimensions:"
[1] "time   Size: 61"
[1] "height   Size: 8"
[1] "lat   Size: 185"
[1] "lon   Size: 64"
[1] "Time   Size: 61"
[1] "DateStrLen   Size: 19"
[1] "------------------------"
[1] "file CF_OUTPUT.nc has 20 variables:"
[1] "float temp[lon,lat,height,time]  Longname:Temperature Missval:1e+30"
[1] "float relh[lon,lat,height,time]  Longname:Relative Humidity Missval:1e+30"
[1] "float airm[lon,lat,height,time]  Longname:Air density Missval:1e+30"
[1] "float z[lon,lat,height,time]  Longname:Layer top altitude Missval:1e+30"
[1] "float ZH[lon,lat,height,time]  Longname:Layer top altitude Missval:1e+30"
[1] "float hlay[lon,lat,height,time]  Longname:Layer top altitude Missval:1e+30"
[1] "float PM10ant[lon,lat,height,time]  Longname:PM10ant Concentration Missval:1e+30"
[1] "float PM10bio[lon,lat,height,time]  Longname:PM10bio Concentration Missval:1e+30"
[1] "float PM10[lon,lat,height,time]  Longname:PM10 Concentration Missval:1e+30"
[1] "float PM25ant[lon,lat,height,time]  Longname:PM25ant Concentration Missval:1e+30"
[1] "float PM25bio[lon,lat,height,time]  Longname:PM25bio Concentration Missval:1e+30"
[1] "float PM25[lon,lat,height,time]  Longname:PM25 Concentration Missval:1e+30"
[1] "float C2H4[lon,lat,height,time]  Longname:C2H4 Concentration Missval:1e+30"
[1] "float CO[lon,lat,height,time]  Longname:CO Concentration Missval:1e+30"
[1] "float SO2[lon,lat,height,time]  Longname:SO2 Concentration Missval:1e+30"
[1] "float NO[lon,lat,height,time]  Longname:NO Concentration Missval:1e+30"
[1] "float NO2[lon,lat,height,time]  Longname:NO2 Concentration Missval:1e+30"
[1] "float O3[lon,lat,height,time]  Longname:O3 Concentration Missval:1e+30"
[1] "char Times[DateStrLen,Time]  Longname:Times Missval:NA"
[1] "float HGT[lon,lat,time]  Longname:Topography Missval:1e+30"

nc.a=get.var.ncdf(NCFile , varid = 'NO2', start=c(1,1,1,1), count=c(-1,-1,1,1))
Pol <- rasterToPolygons(raster(nc.a),dissolve = TRUE)
Pol
class       : SpatialPolygonsDataFrame 
features    : 11829 
extent      : 0, 1, 0, 1  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : NA 
variables   : 1
names       :             layer 
min values  : 0.219758316874504 
max values  :  0.84041428565979 
writeOGR(Pol, dsn = getwd(), layer = 'testPol', driver = 'ESRI Shapefile', overwrite_layer = TRUE)
```

What I get, however, are grided polygons that are not projected.

UPDATE:
Following @kakk11 and @RobertH answers, I  was able to solve part of the problem. I still get a grid-like polygons, not smoothed. Here is what I did so far:
I couldn't extract the variable directly to raster as @RobertH suggested. so I used the 'get.var.ncdf' and then 'raster':

```
NCFileName = 'MyncFile.nc'
NCFile = open.ncdf(NCFileName)
nc.a = get.var.ncdf(NCFile, varid = 'NO2', start=c(1,1,1,13), count=c(-1,-1,1,1))
nc.a = raster(nc.a)
# put in correct extent:
lat  = NCFile$dim$lat$vals
lon  = NCFile$dim$lon$vals
ExtentLat = range(lat)
ExtentLon = range(lon)
rm(lat,lon)

nc.a = flip(t(nc.a), direction='y')

# Give it lat/lon coords 
extent(nc.a) = c(ExtentLon,ExtentLat)
```

Then the 'cut' command returns vector, so i used 'ratser:reclassify':

```
cuts = c(0,5,15,30,50)
classes <- cbind(cuts[1:length(cuts)-1],cuts[2:length(cuts)],cuts[2:length(cuts)])
nc.class <- reclassify(nc.a, classes)
```

I then used the 'rasterToPolygons' with 'dissolve=TRUE' to create the polygons:

```
pol <- rasterToPolygons(nc.class, dissolve = TRUE)
# set UTM projection:
WGS84_Projection = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"
proj4string(pol) <- CRS(WGS84_Projection)
writeOGR(pol, dsn = getwd(), layer = 'file' , driver = 'ESRI Shapefile', overwrite_layer = TRUE)
```

Still, all this creates polygon shapefile with the polygons that are not smooth, which is the main challenge.

Could use some help with this.

Ilik

Comment: I do not quite understand what do You want to achieve here. Converting gridded data to shapefile does not seem reasonable because shapefiles "typically contain data related to coastlines, political boundaries, state or county boundaries, climate zones, roads, rivers, topography, etc". Or is what You want contours of some levels of Your data? So that You get a polygon where value of NO2 exceeds some value?

Comment: The NetCDF files are the output of a model with predicted pollution levels. I need to present them to the general public on the internet, and the webmaster insists that I give him polygon shapefiles and predefined  coloring levels (i.e., intervals of pollution levels). So the polygons will mark the contours at the desired interval, which will include the threshold values for each pollutant. I hope this makes it clearer

Answer (score 2):

You first need correctly create a RasterLayer, like this:

```
 r <- raster('MyncFile.nc', var='NO2')
 # or, to get all time steps at once
 # brick('MyncFile.nc', var='NO2')
```

You could then generalize (classify) the values using reclassify or cut. For example

```
 cuts <- seq(0.2, 0.9, 0.1)
 rc <- cut(r, cuts)
```

Make polygons and save to shapefile

```
 pol <- rasterToPolygons(rc, dissolve = TRUE)
 shapefile(pol, 'file.shp')
```

Comment: Are You sure You can use raster on NCfile directly without getting the variable first? When I try:
    `NCfile<-open.ncdf('myfile.nc')`
and
    `tm2<-raster(NCfile,var="myvar")`
I get 
**Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘raster’ for signature ‘"ncdf"’**

Comment: Sorry that should have been NCFileName, I have fixed that